# CodeIgniter3 Cannot Load File from Views

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

It's been a while since I used to make website using Codeigniter, So I want to open a new page once the button is clicked. But it only showed as

> "Object Not Found. Error 404."

, with `http://localhost/xxxxx/reseller` as the URL.
I've tried to load it on baseurl, put it in the index function, and it can load perfectly.

Here is my code on **Controller** :

```
public function reseller()
{
    $this->load->view('v_reseller');
}
```

**Button**

```
 <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>reseller">Find Out More</a>
```

Comment: What is in your view file and where is it?

Comment: have u load the url helper there

Comment: @GulmuhammadAkbari my file name is v_reseller.php

Comment: Could you please attach your view file contents?

Comment: @pradeep , yes, I already add url on autoload 'helper'.

Comment: what is your default controller

Comment: @GulmuhammadAkbari , I am sorry, but I can't. But I already try to load it on my index page (base url) and it opened just fine.

Comment: @pradeep my default controller is welcome, I code that function there

Comment: are you using routes? a missing controller name in an anchor tag.

Comment: @vallapureddyKarunakarReddy , no, I did not change anything on routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first time you have do the following:

Make empty this variable in your config file `$config['base_url'] = '';`
Check .htaccess in root folder with index.php file
Enable mod_rewrite apache module

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Is your function loaded or not? @dheesMudhiah

Comment: I am not sure is the problem with your view files or controller?

Comment: did you mean the url? yes, but the message still showed

Comment: Create a test view file and load it instead of `v_reseller`, report me back.

Comment: I make a new view file using my home code that works just fine, but I still get the same error message

Comment: Did you get the same error message with the new view file?

Comment: yes, everytime it is on second slash (after base url), it will give me the same message. if I try to load the reseller page on index (base url) function, it shows up fine